# Plotly Dash Heatmap not updating with dropdown selection

Tags: drop-down-menu, plotly, heatmap, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am new to plotly dash and i'm trying to make a heatmap that changes with a dropdown selection. The dropdown is to choose a month, but the heatmap doesn't change!
My data frame is called 'New'.
Here's my code:

```
Month_Default = New['Month'].unique()
Month_def = 2
#create the dash app
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
 html.H1('//Title'),
 html.Div([
 html.Div([
 html.H4('Select Month...'),
 dcc.Dropdown(
 id='Month_dropdown',
 options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in Month_Default],
 value = Month_Def
 ),
 ],
 style={'width': '48%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
 

 dcc.Graph(id='heatmap', 
 figure = {
 'data': [go.Heatmap(
 x=New['Days'].where(New['Month']==2),
 y=New['Hour'],
 z=New['Usage'],
 
 colorscale='Viridis')],
 'layout': go.Layout(
 xaxis = dict(title = 'Days'),
 yaxis = dict( title = 'Hours'),
 )})
 ]),])



@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output(component_id='heatmap',component_property='figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input(component_id='Month_dropdown',component_property='value')]
)



def update_graph(Month_dropdown):
    filtered_df = New[New['Month'] == Month_dropdown]
    heat_fig = go.Heatmap(filtered_df,
                       x='Days', y='Hour', z='Usage',
                       colorscale='Viridis',
                       title='PM KWH Usage')
    return heat_fig
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of your DataFrame `New`, or a similar DataFrame that will run with your code? Currently your issue will be difficult to reproduce because we don't know what `New` looks like

Comment: New is a dataframe that has 4 columns, one column is for ‘Month’ which include the dates of 5 months. One column is for the ‘Hours’ and one for ‘Days’, each day of each month contains 24 hours. The last column is the ‘Usage’, this is the value that I want to display in the heatmap. X axis is for the 30-31 days of the month, y axis is for the 24 hours, z axis is for the usage value during each hour. The dropdown is to choose a month and display the corresponding heatmap. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- have created `New` dataframe in the way you described it in comments
- using **dash** 2.0.0 hence only need to `import dash`
- two key steps missed

  1. did not `app.run_server()` to start the **dash** app
  2. no **callback** to respond to **Dropdown**
- instead of repeating code in **dash layout** and **callback** moved **figure** creation to just the **callback**

```
import dash
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

New = pd.DataFrame(
    {"date": pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", "15-jun-2021", freq="H")}
).assign(
    Usage=lambda d: np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(d)),
    Month=lambda d: d["date"].dt.month,
    Days=lambda d: d["date"].dt.day,
    Hour=lambda d: d["date"].dt.hour,
)

Month_Default = New["Month"].unique()
Month_def = 2
# create the dash app
# app = dash.Dash()
app = JupyterDash(__name__)

app.layout = dash.html.Div(
    [
        dash.html.H1("//Title"),
        dash.html.Div(
            [
                dash.html.Div(
                    [
                        dash.html.H4("Select Month..."),
                        dash.dcc.Dropdown(
                            id="Month_dropdown",
                            options=[{"label": i, "value": i} for i in Month_Default],
                            value=Month_def,
                        ),
                    ],
                    style={"width": "48%", "display": "inline-block"},
                ),
                dash.dcc.Graph(id="heatmap"),
            ]
        ),
    ]
)

@app.callback(Output("heatmap", "figure"), Input("Month_dropdown", "value"))
def updateGraph(value):
    if not value:
        value = Month_def

    return {
        "data": [
            go.Heatmap(
                x=New["Days"].where(New["Month"] == value),
                y=New["Hour"],
                z=New["Usage"],
                colorscale="Viridis",
            )
        ],
        "layout": go.Layout(
            xaxis=dict(title="Days"),
            yaxis=dict(title="Hours"),
            margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
        ),
    }

app.run_server(mode="inline")
```